# Using the lab context helper for HapiJS causes an error

Tags: javascript, testing, hapi.js

I wrote a unit test for HapiJS using [lab](https://github.com/hapijs/lab)

```
beforeEach(async ({ context }) => {
  context.server = new Hapi.Server();
  await context.server.register(Inert);
});

test('/ rootPath is served', async ({ context }) => {
  await context.server.register({
    plugin: require('../server/statics'),
    options: { rootPath }
  });
  const res = await context.server.inject({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/'
  });

  expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
});
```

And I was surprised when the test fails with this error.

```sh
Method Set.prototype.add called on incompatible receiver #<Set>

at Set.add (<anonymous>)
at module.exports.internals.Core.registerServer (/home/xxxx/node_modules/hapi/lib/core.js:217:24)
```

The issue seems to be with the statement to add the server to the `instances`.

```
// /home/xxx/node_modules/hapi/lib/core.js
registerServer(server) {

    if (!this.root) {
        this.root = server;
        this._defaultRoutes();
    }

    this.instances.add(server); // <-- line 217
}
```

which was declared to be a set.

```
    this.dependencies = [];                                                         
    // Plugin dependencies
    this.events = new Podium(internals.events);
    this.heavy = new Heavy(this.settings.load);
    this.instances = new Set(); // <-- line 68
```

I'm wondering why this error occurs and if I'm using the context in the wrong way. I can of course use a variable in the module scope as a workaround but I thought the context helper was [created to avoid having to do that](https://github.com/hapijs/lab#context).